# I am getting an syntax error when using expr

Tags: bash, expr

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
reg='[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9Xx]{1}'
while read ISBN; do
    if [[ $ISBN =~ '$$$' ]]; then
        exit 0
    else
        if [[ $ISBN =~ $reg ]]; then
            ISBN=${ISBN//-/}
            let sum=0
            let k=11
            for index in `seq 1 10`; do
                array[$index]=`echo $ISBN | cut -c"$index"`
                k=$(expr $k - $index)
                n=$(expr $k * ${array[$index]})
                sum=$(expr $sum + $n)
                echo $sum
            done
            #do something
        else
            echo Invaild
        fi
    fi
done
```

My input:

```
0-00-000001-1
```

The error:

```
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
```

but when I run expr in terminal like following:

```
k=11
index=1
echo $(expr $k - $index)
```

it works well.Can you tell me why?

Comment: You don't need to use `expr` at all; use arithmetic expansion: `k=$(($k - $index))`.

Comment: Use `for ((index=0; index < 10; index++))` for the for loop and `${ISBN:$index:1}` in place of the `cut` pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `expr`, you need to escape the `*` to avoid it being expanded as a file glob:

```
n=$(expr $k \* ${array[$index]})
```

With arithmetic expressions, this is not an issue:

```
n=$(( $k * ${array[$index]} ))
```